# The number of heads in $4k$ flips of a $3:1$ biased coin is more likely to exceed $3k$ than to fall short of it. Why is this?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

For instance, if we flip a coin with a $0.75$ probability of seeing heads 8 times, we have a $32.1\%$ chance of seeing $5$ or fewer heads, while we have a $36.7\%$ chance of seeing $7$ or $8$ heads.

In general, suppose we have a coin with probability $\frac{p}{q}$ of landing heads (and otherwise landing tails). We flip the coin in $k\cdot q$ independent trials, and count the number of heads. The expected number (and the most probable outcome) is $k\cdot p$, but how do we compare the odds of seeing more or less than this? Do their discrepancies decrease with increasing $k$, and if so at what rate?

More formally, we're looking to compare (eliminating the common factor of $q^{-kq}$)

$$\sum_{i=0}^{kp-1}{n\choose i}p^{i}(q-p)^{kq-i}\ \ \ \ \textrm{vs.}\ \ \ \ \sum_{i=kp+1}^{kq}{n\choose i}p^{i}(q-p)^{kq-i}$$

Comment: Very intuitively, the left tail of the distribution (of # heads) is longer than the right tail (measured from the mean), since $P(H) > 0.5$. Since the mean is the "see saw balancing point" of the probability mass function, then the shorter right tail suggests more actual outcomes in it to make the balance happen. Or something like that. Maybe .

Comment: What is "time" here? $k$? or $q$? or both?

Comment: Sorry, poor phrasing. $k$.